# Why is jruby / selenium dropping my connection to my browser

Tags: selenium, cucumber, jruby, watir-webdriver

I'm in the process of doing software upgrades and I'm having issues where my tests will start to run, but then all of a sudden the browser will stop responding and I get the following stack trace:

I'm using cucumber (1.3.10), gherkin (2.12.2-java), page-object (0.9.5), watir-webdriver (0.6.6), and selenium-webdriver (2.39.0) with firefox and with chrome with Ruby 1.9.3

I was not having the issue before using cucumber (1.2.3), watir-webdriver(0.6.2) and selenium-webdriver(2.34.0) with ruby 1.8.7

```
Unable to establish loopback connection

org/jruby/RubyIO.java:3673:in `select'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/1.9/net/protocol.rb:143:in `rbuf_fill'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/1.9/net/protocol.rb:141:in `rbuf_fill'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/1.9/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/1.9/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:2570:in `read_status_line'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:2559:in `read_new'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:1327:in `transport_request'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1282:in `catch'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:1324:in `transport_request'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:1301:in `request'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:1294:in `request'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:743:in `start'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:1292:in `request'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:83:in `response_for'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:39:in `request'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:634:in `raw_execute'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:612:in `execute'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:545:in `isElementEnabled'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.39.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:151:in `enabled?'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.6/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:528:in `assert_enabled'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.6/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:119:in `click'
C:/devl/Ruby/features/support/hooks.rb:1177:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1565:in `instance_exec'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:48:in `cucumber_instance_exec'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:69:in `cucumber_run_with_backtrace_filtering'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/core_ext/instance_exec.rb:36:in `cucumber_instance_exec'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_hook.rb:14:in `invoke'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:114:in `invoke'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:108:in `execute_after'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1693:in `reverse_each'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:107:in `execute_after'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:19:in `after'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:112:in `fire_hook'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:111:in `fire_hook'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:113:in `after'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:100:in `before_and_after'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:82:in `with_hooks'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:120:in `around'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:9:in `around'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:91:in `execute_around'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/language_support/language_methods.rb:8:in `around'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:119:in `around'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:271:in `call'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:117:in `around'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:94:in `around'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:81:in `with_hooks'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/outline_table.rb:135:in `accept_expand'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/outline_table.rb:107:in `accept'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/outline_table.rb:25:in `accept'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java:978:in `each_with_index'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/outline_table.rb:23:in `accept'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:90:in `visit_outline_table'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:170:in `broadcast'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:89:in `visit_outline_table'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/examples.rb:25:in `accept'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:80:in `visit_examples'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:170:in `broadcast'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:79:in `visit_examples'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/scenario_outline.rb:19:in `accept'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/scenario_outline.rb:18:in `accept'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:74:in `visit_examples_array'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:170:in `broadcast'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:73:in `visit_examples_array'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/scenario_outline.rb:45:in `accept'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:58:in `visit_feature_element'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:170:in `broadcast'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:57:in `visit_feature_element'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/feature.rb:38:in `accept'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/feature.rb:37:in `accept'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:27:in `visit_feature'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:170:in `broadcast'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:26:in `visit_feature'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:28:in `accept'
org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:17:in `each'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/features.rb:27:in `accept'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:21:in `visit_features'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:170:in `broadcast'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:20:in `visit_features'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:49:in `run!'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/../lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/cucumber:13:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1099:in `load'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/bin/cucumber:1:in `(root)'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1099:in `load'
-e:1:in `(root)'

logout and close windows failed

not able to disable survey

SocketError: Permission denied: no further information
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:762:in `connect'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:762:in `connect'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:755:in `do_start'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:744:in `start'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:743:in `start'
C:/jruby-1.7.10/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb:1292:in `request'
./features/page_objects/clean_slate/welcome/clean_ssc_login_page.rb:23:in `visit_login_page'
./features/step_definitions/common/common_login_steps.rb:60:in `login_user_to_site'
./features/step_definitions/awe_clean_slate/footer.rb:9:in `/^I am logged in as an (.*) user$/'
C:\devl\Ruby\features\SSC\general_site\contact_us.feature:6:in `Given I am logged in as an <role> user'

Skipped step

Skipped step

process for failing scenarios failed

Permission denied: no further information
```

Comment: @user1177636 I'm completely lost... spent the last 3 hours trying to debug

Comment: FYI I have to restart in order to do anything after this happens.

Comment: You say you are in the process of doing software upgrades. Does that mean that you did not have this problem before? Explaining the upgrades you have made between when this worked to when this stopped working might help identify the problem.

Comment: @JustinKo I updated the question to include the following:

I was not having the issue before using cucumber (1.2.3), watir-webdriver(0.6.2) and selenium-webdriver(2.34.0) with ruby 1.8.7.

Comment: Which version of Java do you have? Can you add what `java -version` says? You don't have a firewall that might be blocking traffic on localhost/127.0.0.1/::1, do you? As a second wild guess, try forcing IPv4 over IPv6: `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`

Comment: @Shepmaster Java version 1.7.0_45 and I tried the IPv4Stack switch and it didn't help

Comment: What about firewalls or virus scanners that might otherwise block access to the network stack? The [line of code that is failing](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/1.7.10/lib/ruby/1.9/net/http.rb#L762) seems to be straightforward: `TCPSocket.open(conn_address(), conn_port())`. Perhaps you can try a small program that opens a server socket on localhost and another program that connects to it?

Comment: @Shepmaster I'm really confused because I created a green field project that just opens the browser and navigates around and it works fine, which means their's something in my code that's causing the issue.  I have no idea where to go from here

Comment: The reason it worked is because I didn't thrash the greenfield project like the regular test suite did

Comment: Please clarify the following points: (1a) Do you have a firewall or virus scanner running? (1b) What happens if you disable it? (2) How many *selenium* tests run before this error occurs? (3) Which of selenium/watir/cucumber did your new project use?  One explanation I can make up is that you have a virus scanner that adapts to network traffic. Automated execution triggers the blocking, manual doesn't. Restarting clears the pattern that the virus scanner has. (Again, this is all made up)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran across this problem once based on some other software on my machine blocking JRuby from running these tests.  I found out that McAfee Host Intrusion Prevention seemed to be dropping connection to Selenium when I used JRuby but not regular Ruby.

To check if the service is running, as a system admin go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services and see if **McAfee Host Intrusion Prevention** is listed as Started.

If it is, run **net stop "McAfee Host Intrusion Prevention Service"** in a command prompt window as an admin.  After that completes run a test and the test should complete.